# Trying to create a function that ensures the length of the list is 2

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I am trying to create a function that will check if the length of my list is 2, and if so, it goes on to the next step.  I haven't written the next steps, as I can't get the first step to accurately check.  Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
  my_function <- function(x) {
  if(length(x) <- 2) {
    return("Correct Length") 
  } 
}
```

When I run this function with:

```
my_function(list(c(3)))
my_function(list(c("text")))
my_function(list(c(6, 7), c(2, 4)))
```

I get the following results:

```
[1] "Correct Length"
[1] "Correct Length"
[1] "Correct Length"
```

I am sure this is how I am measuring my length, but if I try to add 'list' to the code.  I am not sure why my function is evaluating the first two items as TRUE, as only the their input should evaluate to TRUE.

Any suggestions would be help as I continue to learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<-` is used for assigning values to variables, `==` is used for checking equality. Your check should thus be

```
if (length(x) == 2) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  So was my function not doing anything, and just printing out the result no matter what I input?